# First Order Logic, help in Unification and substitution process

Tags: first-order-logic, substitution, unification

I'm trying to solve a few unification problems, but this one is a bit tricky to me. I have to demonstrate how to derive the first one starting from the second one.

$\phi$ (c, f(c,h(M,e(c)))

$\phi$ (X, f(X,h(c,V))

considering that upper case letter are variables, else constants and function symbols.

This a cascade unification problem but how to solve this?

Comment: It "sound" strange... you can put $X \leftarrow c$ and $V \leftarrow e(c)$, but if $M$ is a variable, why replace $c$ with a variable ?

Comment: I don't know, this is an excercise. Yes i know that it sound strange.. i think is tha goal of this excercise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When unifying you don't 'derive' the one from the other ... rather, you make substitutions for each of the terms so they match up.

So, use:

$X \leftarrow c$, $M \leftarrow c$, and $V \leftarrow e(c)$